# GraphQL Automatic refetch on empty responses

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo

I want to randomize movies from theMovieDB API. First I send a request to access the ID of the latest entry:

```
const { loading: loadingLatest, error: errorLatest, data: latestData, refetch: refetchLatest } = useQuery(
        LATEST_MOVIE_QUERY
    );
```

Then I want to fetch data from a randomly selected ID between 1 and the number of the latest id. Using a variable dependant on the first query seems to break the app, so for now I'm just using the same movie every time upon mounting the component:

```
const [
        movieState,
        setMovieState
    ] = useState(120);

    const { loading, error, data, refetch } = useQuery(ONE_MOVIE_BY_ID_QUERY, {
        variables : { movieId: movieState },
        skip      : !latestData
    });
```

I want to press a button to fetch a new random movie, but the problem is that many of the IDs in the API lead to deleted entries and then I get an error back. I want to keep refetching until I get a good response back but I have no idea to implement it. Right now my randomize function just looks like this:

```
const randomizeClick = () => {
        let mostRecentID = latestData.latestMovie.id;
        setMovieState(Math.floor(Math.random() * mostRecentID));
    };
```

I'd be grateful if someone can help me how to implement this.

Comment: Assuming you're querying a server you also built, this sort of thing would be better done on the backend. That is, you should just keep retrying your call to TMDb on your server until you get a hit. Retrying on the client side will be that much slower because of the added latency between the server and the client.

Comment: That said, the *best* approach would be to just write a script that would query their API and capture all valid IDs. You could then dump that into a file or DB and just pick a random ID from that set of IDs. Creating a script to do this would mean you could rerun it periodically to ensure your list of IDs was up-to-date.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you needs is the "useLazyQuery" functionality of Apollo. You can find more information about it here: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/queries/#executing-queries-manually

With useLazyQuery you can change your variables easily and this is meant to be fired after a certain event (click or something similar). The useQuery functionality will be loaded when the component is mounted.